# Partitioning a list of numbers the Mathematica way

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have two sorted lists, one list will be called the "fences" and the other the "values"

Fences could be: $\{1, 5, 9, 14\}$

Values could be $\{-1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15\}$

I want to partition the values list using the equivalence relation that they are between the same fence values.  ($f_i \leq v < f_{i+1})$

With the example above, I would get the partition:

$$\{\{-1\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{6\}, \{9, 10, 13\}, \{14,15\}\}$$

This partitioning is quite easy using to implement using a for loop but I can't help but feel there is a better way to do it using some of the inbuilt Mathematica functions.  I am not asking anyone to write the algorithm for me but to suggest which functions I should be aware of in order to do this elegantly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
f = {1, 5, 9, 14};
v = {-1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15};
BinLists[v, {Join[{-Infinity}, f, {Infinity}]}]
```

> {{-1}, {1, 3, 4}, {6}, {9, 10, 13}, {14, 15}}

Comment: I can't believe there is a function to do exactly what I wanted.  Thanks Ray, and to the other people who answered and taught me new things along the way.

Comment: This is much faster than other methods too! +1

Comment: +1 -- for those who like brevity: `BinLists[v, {{-∞, ##, ∞}& @@ f}]`

Answer (score 10):

I'd go with the `BinLists` method. Were that not available, one could do well with a zero-order interpolation. These can be useful if the fence list is large, because lookup is efficient (log(n) rather than n).

I do some negating to get the continuity to be at the left end of the intervals.

```
interp[x_List] := 
 With[{newx = Join[{-10^8}, x, {10^8}]}, 
  Interpolation[Transpose[{Reverse[-newx], Range[Length[newx]]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0]]

v = {-1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15};
f = interp[{1, 5, 9, 14}];
SplitBy[v, f[-#] &]

(* Out[48]= {{-1}, {1, 3, 4}, {6}, {9, 10, 13}, {14, 15}} *)
```

Comment: This so much memory efficient. Tested `BinList` with `f = Union@RandomInteger[{-10^7, 10^7}, 10^5];
v = Sort@RandomInteger[{-10^8, 10^8}, 10^7];` on a 64GB system and MMA9 aborted. Yours worked fine and took mere 56 sec..+1

Answer (score 5):

You can try this!

```
fences = {1, 5, 9, 14};
vals = {-1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15};
Select[vals, #] & /@
(Function[{x}, #1 <= x < #2] & @@@Partition[fences, 2, 1, {2, 1}, {Infinity, -Infinity}])
```

> {{-1}, {1, 3, 4}, {6}, {9, 10, 13}, {14, 15}}

Comment: Thanks PlatoManiac, this uses a lot of stuff I'm unfamiliar with at the moment, which is a good thing.  I'll now try and figure out what exactly you're doing

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way using `SplitBy`

```
fences = {1, 5, 9, 14};
values = {-1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15};
```

Then:

```
SplitBy[values, Function[{z}, #1 <= z < #2] & @@@ Partition[fences, 2, 1]] // 
   Flatten[#, Length[fences] - 2] &
```

Which gives:

```
{{-1}, {1, 3, 4}, {6}, {9, 10, 13}, {14, 15}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    PartIt[{k_List, bb_List}] := 
     Block[{t, a = {}, st, s, b = bb, l = k, 
       bt = Partition[{-Infinity, b /. List -> Sequence, Infinity}, 2,1]},                    
      {Table[If[bt[[i, 1]] <= l[[j]] < bt[[i, 2]], a = {a, {i, l[[j]]}},j],
      {i, 1, Length[bt]}, {j, 1, Length[l]}],
       st = Partition[Flatten[a], 2], 
       s = Map[Rest[#] &, GatherBy[st, First], {2}] // Flatten[#, {3}] &};
       s]
```

b = {1, 5, 9, 14};
l = {-1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15};

```
PartIt[{l, b}]
```

> {{{-1}, {1, 3, 4}, {6}, {9, 10, 13}, {14, 15}}}

```
PartIt[{l + 3, b}]
```

> {{{2, 4}, {6, 7}, {9, 12, 13}, {16, 17, 18}}}